# Search and replace invisible url link in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, isearch

I have following content in a org file:

```
* test
[[file:foo1.pdf][test file1]]
[[file:foo2.pdf][test file2]]
[[file:foo3.pdf][test file3]]
```

Normally, the file name (eg `foo1.pdf`) is folded and invisible. And when I do a search for `foo` (with `ctrl-s`), I can't find anything... How can I enable the isearch for those invisible text? I tried `M-s i` on the isearch command and it does not work.

Comment: `M-s i` causes invisible text to be searched. But, unfortunately it does not make text with `invisible`-text properties visible. This only works for overlays having the `invisible` property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `M-x org-toggle-link-display` or the menu item `Org -> Hyperlinks -> Literal Links` before using `isearch` or `query-replace`.

The following code does that automagically for you when you use `isearch` or `query-replace`/`query-replace-regexp`. It restores the old state when you are done with searching.

The code is tested with Emacs 25.1.50.2.

EDIT: Added `(setq-local search-invisible t)` to search in texts that are hidden by the `invisible` text property.

```el
(defvar-local org-descriptive-links-isearch nil
  "Backup of the original value `org-descriptive-links' before isearch.")

(defun org-isearch-mode-hook-function ()
  "Save value of `org-descriptive-links' before isearch."
  (setq org-descriptive-links-isearch org-descriptive-links))

(defun org-isearch-mode-end-hook-function ()
  "Restore original value of `org-descriptive-links' after isearch."
  (unless (eq org-descriptive-links-isearch org-descriptive-links)
    (org-toggle-link-display)))

(defun org-mode-isearch-filter (found)
  "Toggle to literal links if match is found within a string that is hidden in the target of descriptive links."
  (when (and found
         (text-property-any (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0) 'invisible 'org-link)
         org-descriptive-links)
    (org-toggle-link-display))
  found)

(defun org-query-replace-isearch-wrapper (oldfun &rest args)
  "Toggle to literal links if match is found within a string that is hidden in the target of descriptive links."
  (org-isearch-mode-hook-function)
  (prog1 (apply oldfun args)
    (org-isearch-mode-end-hook-function)))

(defun org-mode-setup-isearch ()
  "Setup some specials for isearch in org-mode.
1. Toggle descriptive links if necessary."
  (setq-local search-invisible t)
  (add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook 'org-isearch-mode-hook-function)
  (add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook 'org-isearch-mode-end-hook-function)
  (add-function :filter-return (local 'isearch-filter-predicate) #'org-mode-isearch-filter)
  (advice-add 'query-replace :around #'org-query-replace-isearch-wrapper)
  (advice-add 'query-replace-regexp :around #'org-query-replace-isearch-wrapper))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-mode-setup-isearch)
```